# How can two similar mysql queries show different results

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL Queries that i am trying to use to balance the db and find issues.

Query 1 for advance totals 286940.99 and query 2 totals 288645.3 which is 1,704.31 different (the advance unallocated is also wrong).

The issue I have is they are both summing the same column the only diffeence been that query 2 has a left join to join another table. The left Join should not affect the primary table at all.

Here are my queries

Query 1

```
  SELECT sum(advance) as advance, sum(advance_unallocated) as advance_unallocated FROM     `deals`
```

Query 2

```
SELECT 

pb.id as pbid,
d.id as did,
sum(d.advance) as advance,
sum(d.advance_unallocated) as advance_unallocated,
sum(pb.payments) as pb_payment,
sum(pb.payments) - sum(d.advance) - sum(d.advance_unallocated) as diff,
pb.payment_method as p_payment_method 

FROM `deals` d 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `payment_balance` pb on d.id = pb.link_id and pb.table_name = 'deals'
```

Comment: Add `COUNT(*)` to both and see the second selects more rows. "The left Join should not affect the primary table at all." --- it does not affect the left table indeed, it affects the result set. `LEFT JOIN` always produces `[N, Inf)` number of rows, where `N` is the number of rows returned without `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: OK done that. one has 49000 and the other 49001 BUT how can that be possible.

Comment: the join condition matches 2 rows. `SELECT * ... GROUP BY d.id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: BUT i thought a LEFT OUTER JOIN would only show the first MATCH or return NULL while as a INNER JOIN will return all MATCHES or return NOTHING on either side. I Used a LEFT OUTER JOIN so surly the primary table should always show the same result.

Comment: No, `LEFT JOIN` returns **all** rows that match join condition or `NULL`s otherwise.

Comment: OK, I am stupid. I will find the dup. Can't believe I never new that. If you want to answer I will accept your answer as a thanks

Comment: I guess this is because the sum value. if i had not used sum it would have joined on one row displayed text and would not have duped the line (as their was nothing to sum), but as I was summing it did. That makes a lot of sense. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `LEFT JOIN` returns not the `[0, 1]` number of rows as you originally thought but **all** the rows that match the join conditions, or a row filled `NULL`s otherwise.

In your particular case there are 1 or more rows that match join condition "unexpectedly".